# How to properly form the requestString for a POST NSUrlRequest on iOS when array values are involved?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, http-post, nsurlrequest

I need to form a POST NSURLRequest and I need to pass into the request this structure:

- inspection (an array of NSDictionaries with string keys and values)
- property (same structure as array1)
- subcategories (an array of NSDictionaries where each dictionary can have an array of values for a certain key)

Here is how my requestString looks like after I concat everything:

```
?inspection[name]=inspection_name&inspection[address]=address_value&...&property[type]=property_type&....&subcategories[0][questions][0][title]=title_value&subcategories[0][questions][1][title]=title_value1&...&subcategories[1][questions][0][title]=title_valuen&...
```

For inspection and property array I've also tried `inspection[][name]=inspection_name, property[][address]=property_address`

While I'm forming that requestString I'm escaping each parameter using this method:

```
static NSString *escapeParam(NSString *param) {
param = [param stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
param = [param stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26"];
param = [param stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D"];
param = [param stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@"%3F"];
return param;
```

}

There fore something like `subcategories[0][questions][0][title]=title_value` becomes `subcategories%5B0%5D%5Bquestions%5D%5B0%5D%5Btitle%5D=title_value`

Obviously I'm doing something wrong and don't know how to properly form this requestString because when I fire the request I get HTTP Error 400 Bad request in response.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all  `&`,`=`,`?` don't need to be encoded, these chars are supported.

Second of all, you don't need to add `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` to the whole body, I think you don't need to add it at all because the server should support escaping chars. If the server doesn't support escaping chars, you should apply the `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` only on the values, the keys should be as tehy are, something like

```
inspection[][name]=[inspection_name stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This will handle eventual escaping chars from your values, but the keys should't have escaping characters since they are created to work on the server.

Comment: You are right with your response and I'll mark this as correct.